# Help identify missing component for jtag connection

Tags: arm, jtag

I found JTAG header for ARM (OMAP3x). It's a Cortex 10-pin 0.05" JTAG/SWD Connector.

(See [here](http://support.code-red-tech.com/CodeRedWiki/HardwareDebugConnections))

I think it's JTAG because PIN#3 and 5 are on GND and it's close of CPU

When I follow the wires, TCK, TDO, TDI goes on missing componant (red circle).

Here is a picture :

[image]

First I was thinking an resistor array of 10K for pull up or pull down signals.

But first, the left side pads doesn't seem to be wired to GND or Vcc

Secondly it would be a 6 resistors array witch is not very common

A last, array resistors have their pads wider on the ends (as the one of 100K*4 on the right bottom of the picture), witch isn't the case here.

1. So what it could be ?
2. Do you think there is a missing resistor on TMS ? as we can see (perhaps) a pad for resistor (go to GND)

Regards

Comment: did you find any connection from the left column  of pads? to me it looks like a pad for a 6x2 connector, e.g. ZIF socket for an FFC or just a shrouded pin connector. Guys over at Electronics may know better.

Comment: I just find GND on center (cf picture updated). Unfortunaly I didn't unwrap the CPU, so I don't know if some pad goes to the CPU.